# Autocomplete combo box perfomance issue

Tags: jquery, performance, combobox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a autocomplete combo box with 10,000 records in database. While i am trying to type APD it will struck.. even application is not working. and showing error like below

Local host not responding due to a long-running script.

if i type 9999 or 243 or 2345 then it is coming without any issue..

Please find my Drop-down values.

```
    APD0000000001 
    APD0000000002
    APD0000000003
    .
    .
    .
    APD0000009999
    APD0000010000
```

**Auto Complete Code**:

```
        function ($) {
        $.widget("custom.combobox", {    
            _create: function () {
                this.wrapper = $("<span>")
              .addClass("custom-combobox")
              .insertAfter(this.element);

                this.element.hide();
                this._createAutocomplete();
                this._createShowAllButton();
            },
            _createAutocomplete: function () {
                var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
              value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

                this.input = $("<input>")
              .appendTo(this.wrapper)
              .val(value)
              .attr("title", "")
              .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
              .autocomplete({
                  delay: 0,
                  minLength: 2,
                  source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
              }).focus(function () { $(this).autocomplete("search"); })
              .tooltip({
                  tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
              });

                this._on(this.input, {
                    autocompleteselect: function (event, ui) {
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;
                        this._trigger("select", event, {
                            item: ui.item.option
                        });
                    },

                    autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
                });
            },

            _createShowAllButton: function () {
                var input = this.input,
              wasOpen = false;

                $("<a>")
              .attr("tabIndex", -1)

              //.attr("title", "Show All Items")
              .tooltip()
              .appendTo(this.wrapper)
              .button({
                  icons: {
                      primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                  },
                  text: false
              })
              .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
              .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
              .mousedown(function () {
                  wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
              })
              .click(function () {
                  input.focus();

                  // Close if already visible
                  if (wasOpen) {
                      return;
                  }

                  // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                  input.autocomplete("search", "");
              });
            },

            _source: function (request, response) {
                var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                response(this.element.children("option").map(function () {
                    var text = $(this).text();
                    if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                        return {
                            label: text,
                            value: text,
                            option: this
                        };
                }));
            },
            _removeIfInvalid: function (event, ui) {

                // Selected an item, nothing to do
                if (ui.item) {
                    return;
                }

                // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
                var value = this.input.val(),
              valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
              valid = false;
                this.element.children("option").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
                        this.selected = valid = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                // Found a match, nothing to do
                if (valid) {
                    return;
                }

                // Remove invalid value
                this.input.val("")
                //.attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
                //.tooltip( "open" );
                this.element.val("");
                this._delay(function () {
                    this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
                }, 2500);
                //this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
            },
            _destroy: function () {
                this.wrapper.remove();
                this.element.show();
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

**Combo box code**

```
        function Speed() {
        (function ($) {
            $.widget("ui.combobox", $.ui.autocomplete,
            {
                options: {
                    /* override default values here */
                    minLength: 2,
                    style: width = 500,
                    /* the argument to pass to ajax to get the complete list */
                    ajaxGetAll: { get: "all" }
                },

                _create: function () {
                    if (this.element.is("SELECT")) {
                        this._selectInit();
                        return;
                    }

                    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._create.call(this)
                    var input = this.element;
                    input.addClass("ui-widget  ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");
                    //  input.addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");
                    this.button = $("<button type='button' >&nbsp;</button>")

                .attr("tabIndex", 1)
                .attr("title", "Show All Items")
                .attr("width", "50px")
                .insertAfter(input)
                .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                    //            .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon")
                .addClass("ui-comboboxstyle")
                .click(function (event) {
                    // close if already visible
                    if (input.combobox("widget").is(":visible")) {
                        input.combobox("close");
                        return;
                    }
                    // when user clicks the show all button, we display the cached full menu
                    var data = input.data("combobox");
                    clearTimeout(data.closing);
                    if (!input.isFullMenu) {
                        data._swapMenu();
                        input.isFullMenu = true;
                    }
                    /* input/select that are initially hidden (display=none, i.e. second level menus), 
                    will not have position cordinates until they are visible. */
                    input.combobox("widget").css("display", "block")
                    .position($.extend({ of: input },
                        data.options.position
                        ));
                    input.focus();
                    data._trigger("open");
                });

                    /* to better handle large lists, put in a queue and process sequentially */
                    $(document).queue(function () {
                        var data = input.data("combobox");
                        if ($.isArray(data.options.source)) {
                            $.ui.combobox.prototype._renderFullMenu.call(data, data.options.source);
                        } else if (typeof data.options.source === "string") {
                            $.getJSON(data.options.source, data.options.ajaxGetAll, function (source) {
                                $.ui.combobox.prototype._renderFullMenu.call(data, source);
                            });
                        } else {
                            $.ui.combobox.prototype._renderFullMenu.call(data, data.source());
                        }
                    });
                },

                /* initialize the full list of items, this menu will be reused whenever the user clicks the show all button */
                _renderFullMenu: function (source) {
                    var self = this,
                    input = this.element,
                    ul = input.data("combobox").menu.element,
                    lis = [];
                    source = this._normalize(source);
                    input.data("combobox").menuAll = input.data("combobox").menu.element.clone(true).appendTo("body");
                    for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
                        lis[i] = "<li class=\"ui-menu-item\" role=\"menuitem\"><a class=\"ui-corner-all\" tabindex=\"-1\">" + source[i].label + "</a></li>";
                    }
                    ul.append(lis.join(""));
                    this._resizeMenu();
                    // setup the rest of the data, and event stuff
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        self._setupMenuItem.call(self, ul.children("li"), source);
                    }, 0);
                    input.isFullMenu = true;
                },

                /* incrementally setup the menu items, so the browser can remains responsive when processing thousands of items */
                _setupMenuItem: function (items, source) {
                    var self = this,
                    itemsChunk = items.splice(0, 500),
                    sourceChunk = source.splice(0, 500);
                    for (var i = 0; i < itemsChunk.length; i++) {
                        $(itemsChunk[i])
                    .data("item.autocomplete", sourceChunk[i])
                    .mouseenter(function (event) {
                        // self.menu.activate(event, $(this));
                    })
                    .mouseleave(function () {
                        // self.menu.deactivate();
                    });
                    }
                    if (items.length > 0) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            self._setupMenuItem.call(self, items, source);
                        }, 0);
                    } else { // renderFullMenu for the next combobox.
                        $(document).dequeue();
                    }
                },


                /* overwrite. to cleanup additional stuff that was added */
                destroy: function () {
                    if (this.element.is("SELECT")) {
                        this.input.remove();
                        this.element.removeData().show();
                        return;
                    }
                    // super()
                    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype.destroy.call(this);
                    // clean up new stuff
                    this.element.removeClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");
                    this.button.remove();
                },

                /* overwrite. to swap out and preserve the full menu */
                search: function (value, event) {
                    var input = this.element;
                    if (input.isFullMenu) {
                        this._swapMenu();
                        input.isFullMenu = false;
                    }
                    // super()
                    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype.search.call(this, value, event);
                },

                _change: function (event) {
                    abc = this;
                    if (!this.selectedItem) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(this.element.val()) + "$", "i"),
                        match = $.grep(this.options.source, function (value) {
                            return matcher.test(value.label);
                        });
                        if (match.length) {
                            match[0].option.selected = true;
                        } else {
                            // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                            this.element.val("");
                            if (this.options.selectElement) {
                                this.options.selectElement.val("");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._change.call(this, event);
                },

                _swapMenu: function () {
                    var input = this.element,
                    data = input.data("combobox"),
                    tmp = data.menuAll;
                    data.menuAll = data.menu.element.hide();
                    data.menu.element = tmp;
                },

                /* build the source array from the options of the select element */
                _selectInit: function () {
                    var select = this.element.hide(),
                selected = select.children(":selected"),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
                    this.options.source = select.children("option[value!='']").map(function () {
                        return { label: $.trim(this.text), option: this };
                    }).toArray();
                    var userSelectCallback = this.options.select;
                    var userSelectedCallback = this.options.selected;
                    this.options.select = function (event, ui) {
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;
                        if (userSelectCallback) userSelectCallback(event, ui);
                        // compatibility with jQuery UI's combobox.
                        if (userSelectedCallback) userSelectedCallback(event, ui);
                    };
                    this.options.selectElement = select;
                    //                this.input = $("<select>").insertAfter(select)
                    //                           .val(value).combobox(this.options);;
                    this.input = $("<input>").insertAfter(select)
                    .val(value).combobox(this.options);
                }
            }
    );
        })(jQuery);
    }
```

Comment: Can we see your SQL query?

Comment: var ECSIDs = APDDb.apds.Select(c => c.ECSAPDId).Distinct();
                                                                                           ViewData["ECSID"] = new SelectList(ECSIDs.AsEnumerable(). OrderByDescending(c => c.ToString()), "ECSID");

Comment: I would say it is cos you are fetching 10,000 rows and transfering them to the client and than on the client you are doing the search. Why not just return the first 5 in the query but make the request each time you type something. This is the usual approach with autocomplete controls on web.